# SSO using Facebook

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I’ve configured SSO using JDBC user store for: my application, API Store and API Publisher. When I log in to my application and move to API Store or API Publisher, then I am automatically logged in.

I added Facebook to be the additional Identity Provider according to the documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Facebook.

I can log in on my website using Facebook data, however I am not logged in when I move to API Store or API Publisher. I have to click log in and provide data once again in API Store/Publisher.

Is there a possibility to have logging in via Facebook work the same as using JDBC user store?

I'm using WSO2 IS 5.7.0 and API Manager 2.6.0

Thanks.

Comment: You may have a look at following resource https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+API+Manager+for+SSO#ConfiguringAPIManagerforSSO-Step2-ConfigurePublisher/StoreforSSO

Comment: What is the difference between your application and the website? According to your description, they seem to be different entities. Are you using the same application from facebook side for all of these?